# Loop through folders and only copy files that match certain criteria

Tags: vb.net, loops, file-io, copy, preserve

I am writing a program that copies certain files needed from one folder to another. However, I only want it to copy files that fit certain criteria, More specifically, it should only copy files that are not in the banned files, banned extensions, or banned folders list as stored in an array like this:

```
Public BannedExtensions As String() = {".bak", ".bak2", ".cry", ".max", ".psd", 
       "log", ".lib", "pdb", ".exp"}
Public BannedFolders As String() = {"Tools", "Editor", "Code", "LogBackups",
       "statoscope", "BinTemp", "USER", "rc"}
Public BannedFiles As String() = {"Editor.exe", "error.bmp", "error.dmp", 
       "luac.out", "tags.txt"}
```

The code should then move them to a temporary directory and then zip them up and save them to the location stored in the `File_Name` variable.

This is my code as a whole:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

    'define the two variables used for tracking file name and where to save'
    Private Property Root_Folder As String
    Private Property File_Name As String

    'define the variable which dictates wether we copy the file
    Private Property copy As Boolean

    'define which files we need and do not need'
    Public BannedExtensions As String() = {".bak", ".bak2", ".cry", ".max", ".psd", "log", ".lib", "pdb", ".exp"}
    Public BannedFolders As String() = {"Tools", "Editor", "Code", "LogBackups", "statoscope", "BinTemp", "USER", "rc"}
    Public BannedFiles As String() = {"Editor.exe", "error.bmp", "error.dmp", "luac.out", "tags.txt"}

    Function Copy_RequiredFiles() As Integer
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        'Searches directory and it's subdirectories for all files, which "*" stands for
        'Say for example you only want to search for jpeg files... then change "*" to "*.jpg"  
        For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Root_Folder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            copy = True

            Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
            Dim fExtension As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(filename)
            Dim fFolder As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)

            For i = 0 To BannedExtensions.Length - 1
                If fExtension = BannedExtensions(i) Then
                    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "Extension: " & filename
                    copy = False
                End If
            Next
            If copy = True Then
                i = 0
                For i = 0 To BannedFolders.Length - 1
                    If filename = BannedFolders(i) Or BannedFolders(i).Contains(filename) Then
                        RichTextBox1.Text = CStr(CBool(RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "Folder: " &
                        copy) = False)
                    End If
                Next
                If copy = True Then
                    i = 0
                    For i = 0 To BannedFiles.Length - 1
                        If filename = BannedFolders(i) Or BannedFolders(i).Contains(filename) Then
                            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "Folder: " & filename
                            copy = False
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            If copy = True Then
                'copy the file into the selected folder'
            End If
        Next
        Return 0
    End Function

    'when the browse button for selecting the folder is selected'
    Private Sub Browse_Root_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browse_Root.Click
        'check if the folder dialogue has been opened successfully and something has been selected'
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then '
            'set the textbox and the previously defined variable to the folder selected'
            TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Root_Folder = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

    'when the browse button for where to save the file is selected'
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'set the options to limit the save type to a zip file'
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "zip files (*.zip)|*.zip"
        'check that the dialogue box has opened succesfully'
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'set the text box and the previously defined variable to the file selected'
            TextBox2.Text = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()
            File_Name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()
        End If
    End Sub

    'when the user changes the value of the textbox update the folder to select from'
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Root_Folder = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    'when the user changes the value of the textbox update the file to save to'
    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        File_Name = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Copy_RequiredFiles()
    End Sub
End Class


'when the browse button for selecting the folder is selected'
Private Sub Browse_Root_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browse_Root.Click
    'check if the folder dialogue has been opened successfully and something has been selected'
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then '
        'set the textbox and the previously defined variable to the folder selected'
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        Root_Folder = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub

'when the browse button for where to save the file is selected'
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'set the options to limit the save type to a zip file'
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "zip files (*.zip)|*.zip"
    'check that the dialogue box has opened succesfully'
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'set the text box and the previously defined variable to the file selected'
        TextBox2.Text = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()
        File_Name = SaveFileDialog1.FileName()
    End If
End Sub

'when the user changes the value of the textbox update the folder to select from'
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Root_Folder = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

'when the user changes the value of the textbox update the file to save to'
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    File_Name = TextBox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Copy_RequiredFiles()
End Sub
End Class
```

I have a couple of questions,

first of which, is why when I run the program and print the files it found that it shouldn't copy, it does not show anything from the second or third if statements in the loop.

Second of which is how would I preserve the folder structure when copying to the temporary file.

And third is, what is the best way to zip up this temporary folder.

Thanks in advance,
Marcus

Comment: `it does not show anything from the second or third if statements in the loop` the variable `copy` starts out false and is not changed in the first If block, so the 2nd, 3rd never execute.

Comment: Yeah, in fact copy is never set to true that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will update my post, I started without any of that checking and it still wasn't working then

Comment: Actually, after looking at it again, the reason I did that is that if it matches something in the first if statement, then it doesn't need to check the rest of the if statements because it shouldn't be copied anyway (correct me if I am wrong). Then this process is repeated for each file in the first for each statement (`For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Root_Folder, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`)

Comment: a) turn on Option Strict and fix the errors b) UI controls make horrible variables.  Save the qualified files in a List to be processed elsewhere c) if you want to preserve a file structure, the path will need to be saved as well (or a FileInfo object) d) for zipping fix the rest first then ask as a separate question.  e) if the file is in the List you create, then skip test 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, a) I turned on Option Strict and fixed the errors (Will update post with new code now). b) I was mainly using the text box to make it easier to debug (I know I can use the console as well) c) I do not fully understand that but will open a new question as I will do for d as well

Do you have anymore suggestions for how to fix the fact that it is still not working properly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a custom class in a List to save the info:

```
Class myFile
   ' to do all the things you want ("preserve folder struct"),
   ' you need more than a name in a textbox:
   Public Property FileName As String
   Public Property FileExt As String
   Public Property PathName As String

   ' cant create a new obj without the essential info
   Public Sub New(fName As String, fExt as String, pName As String)
      FileName = fName
      FileExt = fExt
      PathName = pName
   End SUb

End Class
```

Or, rather than recreate the wheel, use `System.IO.FileInfo` and change how you iterate the files.  Then a list to store these things:

```
Friend myFileList As List(of myFile)
' or
Friend myFileList As List(of FileInfo)
```

To iterate saving to a List(of myFile):

```
Dim myF As MyFile
For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles

    ' if BannedFiles is a List(Of String) instead of an array:
    If BannedFiles.Contains(f.Extension) = False Then
         ' create NEW file object with the info 
         myF = New MyFile(IO.Path.GetFileName(filename),
                          IO.Path.GetExtension(filename),
                          IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename))
         ' add to the list of files to do
         myFileList.Add(f)
    End If

    If myFileList.Contains(f) = False Then         ' better version of Copy=true
        For n As Integer = 0 To BannedFoldersLIST.Count - 1
           If f.FullPath.Contains(BannedFoldersLIST(n)) = False Then

              ' create a new file object as above
                myFileList.Add(f)              ' add for folder ban
           End If
        Next n
    End If

    ' repeat for banned extensions  (watch out for "." vs no dot)

   Return myFileList             ' mine is a function returning
                                 ' a List(Of T) to be processed elsewhere
```

This is more conceptual than code to copy and paste.  Since you want to do several things with the result, it is better to save them in something other than a TextBox.  VS will happily show you what is in the list with the mouse.

The folder test will need work depending on whether the Banned string is a full or partial name.  The larger point is that a List object will tell you if you have already stored an item using `.Contains` rather than a global flag.  Either a `List(Of FileInfo)` or `List(Of myFileClass)` will work.  The latter will preserve more of the code you have.