# vb.net - ReDim Preserve - check if entry is valid

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array of my custom classes:

```
Public foldersList(1) As folderEntry
Public lastFolderId As Integer = 0
```

I'm adding new entries like this:

```
    foldersList(lastFolderId) = New folderEntry(...)
    lastFolderId += 1
    ReDim Preserve foldersList(lastFolderId + 1)
```

It works good, but when it comes to looping through the whole array, my program crashes when it comes to the newly redimmed index. How can I check if the current entry in loop is invalid and is just a placeholder? I know that I could use loop with incrementing variable but I'm trying to do it using `For Each`.

Following `If` statement doesn't work and produces an error.

```
For Each folder As folderEntry In foldersList
    If Not folder = Nothing Then
```

**Error:** Operator '=' is not defined for types 'myAppName.folderEntry' and 'myAppName.folderEntry'.

Optional question: What is the most effective way of storing custom classes?

Comment: I am not sure the error msg and the line indicated match, but almost always if something can be Nothing you dont use `=` for testing that item/object.  Instead try `If folder IsNot Nothing Then`...  Also, a `List` would work better than an array

Comment: try `If Not folder Is Nothing Then`...

Comment: You should use a `List(Of T)` instead of using an array - it will make your life much easier.

Comment: @Plutonix, I've thought that one can experience this kind of problems only in Java. Thanks, it works now. I'll also consider using List. Once again, thanks for help!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23696620/1070452) shows how to use a `List(of myClass)` with file type stuff - they are much, much easier to use than arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Is` or `IsNot` operator when you want to check if a reference-type variable is `Nothing` (null).  For instance:

```
For Each folder As folderEntry In foldersList
    If folder IsNot Nothing Then
    End If
Next
```

As Matt Wilko mentioned in the comments below, VB.NET does technically allow you to use the test `= Nothing`, but it has a different meaning.  Rather than checking to see if the variable is null, the equality operator converts `Nothing` to the default value of the variable's type, then compares that with the value of the variable.  This can lead to unexpected behavior, so as a general rule, I recommend never using `= Nothing` except when you really don't know what the default value for a particular type is.  For instance, here's an example that shows how `= Nothing` works differently than you probably expect.

```
Dim x As String = ""
If x = Nothing Then
    ' This code will be executed because "" = CStr(Nothing)
End If
If x Is Nothing Then
    ' This code will not be executed because x points to an empty string, but it is not null
End If
```

However, none of that would be an issue if you just switched the order so that you resize the array *before* adding the new item rather than after:

```
Public foldersList() As folderEntry
Public lastFolderId As Integer = -1

' ...

lastFolderId += 1
ReDim Preserve foldersList(lastFolderId)
foldersList(lastFolderId) = New folderEntry(...)
```

However, not only is that more difficult to do than just using a `List(Of folderEntry)` object, it's also far less efficient.  Every time you resize the array, it has to create a whole new array, then copy the contents from the old array to the new one, and then delete the old array.  That's a lot of unnecessary work being done.  If you know the total number of items that you'll need before you start, just create the array with the correct size at the beginning.  If you don't, you would be much better off using a `List(Of folderEntry)` object, like this:

```
Public foldersList As New List(Of folderEntry)()

' ...

foldersList.Add(New folderEntry(...))

' ...

For Each folder As folderEntry In foldersList
    ' No need to check if folder is Nothing
Next
```

Comment: Your first line is correct for reference types, `= Nothing` can be used on value types (whether it *should* or not is a debatable point)

Comment: @MattWilko Good point.  I should have mentioned that.  I'll add it.  Thanks.